# X11 forwarded app displays some text wrong

Tags: ssh, fedora, x11, fonts

I am running some apps off my Fedora box over SSH and noticed some apps are displaying some text wrong.
Examples:
[image]
[image]

It isn't isolated to my machine though, it displays like that on macOS too.

If there is some package I am missing that fixes this please tell me.

Comment: Does the fedora box have graphical system like Xorg? most of the times these issues are related to fonts.

Comment: Basically I installed Fedora Server and then followed this https://www.osradar.com/configure-x11-forwarding-in-centos-rhel-6-7-8-and-fedora-28-29/ and then installed virt-manager. I had done this before and the fonts worked fine, but I fked up the install and had to reinstall, after which I reinstalled and did the same as above and it resulted in these issues.

Comment: Since it's fedora server it does not have xorg utitlities and proper font packs. I suggest to check xorg logs while having x11 forwarded, maybe you can find errors. `ls -l /var/log/Xorg*`

Comment: I tried but /var/log/Xorg directory does not exist it says. It's strange because the text next to it works fine but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spun up a VM with a fresh install and followed what I usually did and none of the issues above happened again so yeah think that solves that.

UPDATE: I found that the java-1.8.0-openjdk package comes with xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 and that breaks the fonts because when I remove the package fonts work again.

So that working fonts and java could coexist peacefully I went to https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp and used their RPM following their instructions and bam it works!